# using local endpoint with boto2

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, localstack

I am trying to mock AWS s3 api calls using boto2.
I create local s3 endpoint using [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) and can use this using boto3 easily as below,

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url='http://localhost:4572')
bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
```

But I did not find way to do this using boto2. Is there any way preferably using ~/.boto or ~/.aws/config?

Tried providing endpoint with boto2 but it failed.

```
import boto
boto.s3.S3RegionInfo(name='test-s3-region', endpoint='http://127.0.0.1:4572/')
s3 = boto.s3.connect_to_region('test-s3-region')
print s3.get_bucket('test-poc')
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_bucket'
```

I am looking to use local endpoints for all AWS services for testing purpose.

Comment: I have already specified error message. Additionally I have also looked at boto configuration but did not find way to specify s3 endpoint.

Comment: how about `s3 = boto.s3.S3RegionInfo(name='test-s3-region', endpoint='http://127.0.0.1:4572/').connect()`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
region = boto.s3.S3RegionInfo(name='test-s3-region', endpoint='http://127.0.0.1:4572/', connection_cls=S3Connection)
conn = region.connect()
print conn.get_bucket('test-poc')
```

You need to set the [connection_cls](https://github.com/coreos/depot_tools/blob/master/third_party/boto/s3/__init__.py) attribute [wish is NoneType by default](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3).

Comment: How would you set the sigv4 & access/secret information this way? still trying to decode the manual on this