# Using boto (not boto3) with DigitalOcean Spaces

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, digital-ocean, boto3

I'm hoping for sample code using boto (not boto3) for writing an object to DigitalOcean's Spaces system and then reading it back.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757021/using-local-endpoint-with-boto2) suggested one approach to get started, but the following code produces the result `None`:

```
import boto

s3 = boto.s3.S3RegionInfo(name='nyc3', 
                          endpoint='https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
                          aws_access_key_id=XXXX,
                          aws_secret_access_key=XXXX).connect()
print s3
```

Spaces has the same API as Amazon S3, so I'm hoping boto will work.

(Why do I want to use boto instead of boto3?  Answer: I have boto3 code working perfectly in my test system, but it fails in what seems to be unpredictable ways when operating at scale, and the fail seems to be inside boto3.  If I can get the code working in boto, it is not only a workaround, but would suggest there is a boto3 problem.)

Comment: Am moving on from this question.  Turns out that the perhaps-bug in boto3 was actually due to instability in the DigitalOcean Spaces system.